# Specification of mark-up format included in facebook open graph text

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When I am performing Open Graph requests, some of the responses that I am expecting to be text are having some kind of markup included. For example, when I am requesting the Name and Description of an album, in the description I get something like `\u0040[12412421421:124:The Link]`. (The `\u0040` is actually the `@` sign.)

In this case it seems that what it is saying is that the 'The Link' should be a hyperlink to a facebook page with ID 12412421421. I presume there is similar kind of markup for hashtags and external URLs.

I am trying to find some official documentation or description for this, but I can't seem to find any documentation of this (I might be looking with the wrong keywords).

Is there any online documentation that describes this? And better still is there an PHP library or function already available somewhere that converts this text into its HTML equivalent?

I am using this [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk), but it doesn't seem to offer any such function. (Not sure if there is anything in the new version 4.0 one but I can't use it anyway for now because it requres PHP 5.4+ and my host currently is still on 5.3.).

Comment: Which request are you doing when you get that?

Comment: In this case it is a photo album of a page using `https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/albums`. The `description` of some albums happens to have a link to another Facebook page encoded in this way. I don't know if it is some kind of markdown or something. You can see it here on Graph Explorer (scroll down to the "MODA MALTA 2014" entry and see the description): https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=423178821079990%2Falbums&version=v2.2

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I did. Would be good if someone who knew how to decode them answered though in the meantime :(

Comment: @jbx what's the link to the bug report?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/779313015473718/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the PHP SDK doesn't provide anything to deal with these links and the documentation doesn't document that either. However the API gives all the information you need in the `description` field itself, so here is what you could do:

```
$description = "Live concert with @[66961492640:274:Moonbootica] "
             . "in @[106078429431815:274:London, United Kingdom]! #music #house";

function get_html_description($description) {
    return 
        // 1. Handle tags (pages, people, etc.)
        preg_replace_callback("/@\[([0-9]*):([0-9]*):(.*?)\]/", function($match) {
            return '<a href="http://facebook.com/'.$match[1].'">'.$match[3].'</a>';
        },

        // 2. Handle hashtags
        preg_replace_callback("/#(\w+)/", function($match) {
            return '<a href="http://facebook.com/hashtag/'.$match[1].'">'.$match[0].'</a>';
        },

        // 3. Handle breaklines
        str_replace("\n", "<br />", $description)));
}

// Display HTML
echo get_html_description($description);
```

While `2.` and `3.` handle hashtags and breaklines, the part `1.` of the code basically splits up the tag `@[ID:TYPE:NAME]` into 3 groups of information (id, type, name) before generating HTML links from the page IDs and names:

```
Live concert with <a href="http://facebook.com/66961492640">Moonbootica</a> in <a href="http://facebook.com/106078429431815">London, United Kingdom</a>! <a href="http://facebook.com/hashtag/music">#music</a> <a href="http://facebook.com/hashtag/house">#house</a>
```

> Live concert with [Moonbootica](http://facebook.com/66961492640) in [London, United Kingdom](http://facebook.com/106078429431815)!
>   [#music](http://facebook.com/hashtag/music) [#house](http://facebook.com/hashtag/house)

---

FYI and even if it's not much useful, here are the meanings of the types:

- an app (128),
- a page (274),
- a user (2048).

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, where did you get the information about 128, 274 and 2048? And is there any other possible markup that I need to handle? Maybe links which don't go to Facebook? What about hashtags?

Comment: I found it myself while testing. As much as I know, the only other possible markups you'd meet are the linebreaks `\n` and the hashtags. I've edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

the @ describes a tag to someone,facebook id doesnt make difference between a fanpage or a single person so you gotta deal with php only.and the @ should be the only char that describes a person/page tagged

Comment: There are also hashtags which start with a # character.

Comment: There are also breaklines which are represented with `\n`.

Answer (score -1):

The markup is used to reference a fanpage.

Example:

```
"description": "Event organised by @[303925999750490:274:World Next Top Model MALTA]\nPhotography by @[445645795469650:274:Pixbymax Photography]"
```

The `303925999750490` is the fanpage ID. The `World Next Top Model MALTA` is the name of fanpage. (Don't know what the `274` means)

When you render this on your page, you can render like this:

```
Event organised by <a href="https://facebook.com/303925999750490">World Next Top Model MALTA</a>
Photography by <a href="https://facebook.com/445645795469650">Pixbymax Photography</a>
```

Comment: Yes, that was quite obvious, you just said what I said in my question. What I am looking for is the full specification of what these tags can be. Are there any other possible special characters like the @ ? For instance some kind of markup of links that don't go to facebook? I need a generic answer about how to handle all possible cases.